# Применение функции XOR для значения в hex

Tags: c++, c

Имею 2 значения в формате hex представленном в массиве char

8dcd8130d550168cc2ce3352e0a834d1

06905e6ea2994d929c1f1f5d753b793a

Необходимо применить к ним функцию XOR, но если применять вот так:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<32; i++)
 {
    c[i] = (char)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
 }
```

то получится результат XOR для этих массивов, а мне нужно посчитать для самих значений hex, т.е. для парных символов.

8d cd 81 30 d5 50 16 8c c2 ce 33 52 e0 a8 34 d1

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать?
По идее результат должен получится такой:

8b5ddf5e77c95b1e5ed12c0f95934deb

Comment: код прост - нужно перевести с "хекса" в "нормальный вид", сделать нужные операции, а потом назад перевести в "хекс"

Comment: @KoVadim, нормальный это десятичный?)

Comment: Перевести из строки, как оно у Вас, видимо, записано, в число.

Comment: нормальный - это в массив unsigned char

Comment: @KoVadim, понял, спасибо. сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    std::string str1 = "8dcd8130d550168cc2ce3352e0a834d1";
    std::string str2 = "06905e6ea2994d929c1f1f5d753b793a";
    std::stringstream stream;

    // если строки точно будут одной длины, то этот код можно убрать
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    std::string *to_in = (len1>len2) ? &str2 : &str1;

    for(int i=0, k = abs(len1-len2); i<k; ++i)
        to_in->insert(0, "0");
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for(int i=0; i<str1.length(); i+=2){
        unsigned char x1 = std::stoi(str1.substr(i, 2), nullptr, 16);
        unsigned char x2 = std::stoi(str2.substr(i, 2), nullptr, 16);
        unsigned int r = x1^x2;
        if(r<=15) stream << '0';
        stream << std::hex <<  r;
    }
    std::string result = stream.str();
    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @wololo т.е. вывод должен быть `"000000000000000f"` ?

Comment: @wololo исправлено.